# Electric lines of force of not point like bodies

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

We know how electric lines are force are depicted for point charges. But what about a continuous body like sphere or plate? The sphere's one is drawn just like that of a point charge and that of the plate us drawn perpendicular to the plan of the field. But what is the proof that these are the cases actually? I am not sure how they go defining this from point objects to massive objects. Kindly enlighten me with the concepts.

Comment: This is explained/derived in any book on electromagnetism, and it is likely at least *heuristically* explained in introductory physics texts. Have you looked these things up yet?

Comment: @march I don't remember any physics book I used spending more than a page or two on how to draw field lines. Mainly because they're mostly treated as a not very useful tool these days.

Comment: @ThePhoton. But, the facts that the field (in electrostatic equilibrium) at the surface of a conductor is perpendicular to the surface and that the field (outside) of a uniformly charged sphere is the same as that of a point charge are important things, and well covered in a lot books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Field lines of a field $\vec E(\vec r)$ are defined as lines $\vec r(\lambda)$ such that $$\frac{d}{d\lambda} \vec r (\lambda)=\vec E(\vec r(\lambda ))$$

For the point particle and a charges sphere, outside the sphere the $\vec E$ field is the same so the field lines $\vec r$ are also the same.

Between a pair of infinite plates of equal and opposite charge densities the field is $\vec E = (\sigma/\epsilon_0,0,0)$ where the $x$ direction is perpendicular to the plates. Solving the equation above gives that the field lines are $$\vec r(\lambda)=\left(x_0+\frac{ \sigma}{\epsilon_0}\lambda,y_0,z_0\right)$$ which indeed are straight lines perpendicular to the plates.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the proofs for the [uniqueness theorem](https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/em/lectures/node62.html)

This states that for a charge distribution there is a unique potential for Poisson's equation, or Laplace's equation.

Thus if you have an extended body, and there is charge on it, (or in it if it is a dielectric) and you can find the potential then that is the only solution. So a lot of energy has gone into finding solutions to Poisson and Laplace's equations analytically, usually using symmetry to help find the analytical solution to the differential equation, or numerically.

If you know the potential, you can also find the electric field from the gradient, as well as the surface charge by considering the boundary conditions.

You can still use the principle of superposition to help you find solutions, and visually it can be helpful to plot or draw out the potential lines and electric field lines to see if your solutions match your expectations.

For some cases like spheres, and planes it is also useful to consider the method of images to help you find the potentials.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the electric fields around a continuous object are derived using integration (at least for now - you will be shown more convenient ways to do it later). Essentially, you use an integral to divide the charge distribution into infinitely tiny pieces, and then treat each of those tiny pieces as point charges. This is quite an accurate model, because any real-life charge distribution is really just a collection of tiny point charges (protons or electrons) whose individual electric fields can be summed up to get the overall value.